# Finding words with upper case and printing them via number

Tags: c

I want to write a code that will count uppercase letters and find the word with the most uppercase letters but it does not work, can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1  /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

int main() {
  int i, c, nw, word, state, uc;
  state = OUT;
  uc = word = nw = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
      state = OUT;

    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
      ++uc;
      if (uc > word)
        uc = word;
    }

    if (c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t') {
      state = IN;
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n", word);
}```
````

Comment: Please use [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification) like [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper). While it's highly unlikely you'll ever come across something other than ASCII encoding, there are valid encodings where a condition like `c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'` will be false for an upper-case character.

Comment: `word` is never assigned a value.

Comment: As for your problem, well first of all you're not checking your state (which doesn't seem to be needed anyway); And the condition `c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t'` will *always* be true.

Comment: may I try to compare every character to the array with the uppercase alphabet?

Comment: [@Cheatah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71808451/finding-words-with-upper-case-and-printing-them-via-number#comment126896805_71808451) "`word` is never assigned a value." is not supported by OP's `uc = word = nw = 0;`.

Comment: ..but it does not work.. - so make it, that is will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the input word.
Also, why don't you use `scanf` instead of `getchar()`?

One way could be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* assuming maximum chars in a word = 100 */
#define MAXWORDLEN 100

int main(void)
{
    char word[MAXWORDLEN + 1], longest[MAXWORDLEN + 1];
    int i, c, uclen, maxlen = 0;

    while (scanf("%100s", word) == 1) {
        if (strlen(word) == MAXWORDLEN && (c = getchar()) != EOF && !isspace(c)) {
                printf("Word longer than 100 chars supplied. Aborting...\n");
                abort();
            }

        uclen = 0;
        for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
            if (isupper(word[i]))
                uclen++;

        if (uclen > maxlen) {
            maxlen = uclen;
            strcpy(longest, word);

            if (maxlen == MAXWORDLEN)
                break;
        }
    }

    if (maxlen > 0)
        printf("Longest uppercase letter word: %s\n", longest);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to stick to `getchar()` to accept input then you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* assuming maximum chars in a word = 100 */
#define MAXWORDLEN 100

int main(void)
{
    char word[MAXWORDLEN + 1], longest[MAXWORDLEN + 1];
    int i, c, uclen, maxlen;

    i = uclen = maxlen = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            if (uclen > maxlen) {
                maxlen = uclen;
                word[i] = '\0';
                strcpy(longest, word);

                if (maxlen == MAXWORDLEN)
                    break;
            }
            i = uclen = 0;
        } else if (i >= MAXWORDLEN) {
                printf("Word longer than 100 chars supplied. Aborting...\n");
                abort();
        } else {
            word[i++] = c;
            if (isupper(c))
                uclen++;
        }
    }

    if (uclen > maxlen) {
        maxlen = uclen;
        word[i] = '\0';
        strcpy(longest, word);
    }

    if (maxlen > 0)
        printf("Longest uppercase letter word: %s\n", longest);

    return 0;
}
```